# Use PriorityQueue after overriding equals and compareTo

Tags: java, equals, comparable

I have a class Vertex which implements Comparable and overrides equals.

```
public class Vertex  implements Comparable<Vertex>{

private final int x;
private final int y;
private final char c;

public Vertex(int x, int y, char c) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.c=c;

}

public double heuristic(Vertex goal){   
    double dx = Math.abs(x - goal.x);
    double dy = Math.abs(y - goal.y);
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(dx, 2)+Math.pow(dy, 2));
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    return ("(" + x + "," + y + ")"+"["+c+"]"); 
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Vertex v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(this.heuristic(end)<v.heuristic(end)) return -1;
    return 1;
}
public boolean equals(Vertex v){
     if(this.x==v.x && this.y==v.y) return true;
     return false;
 }

/*
public boolean equals(Object o){
    if(o.getClass().getName()=="Vretex"){
        Vertex v=(Vertex)o;
        return this.equals(v);
    }
    return false;
} 
*/

}
```

When I use PriorityQueue and check if one object (different objects) that equal functionality according the equal function is in the PriorityQueue I get false.

Also tried the one in comment without success.

Answer (score 1):

Your equals is wrong, it should be

```
@Override public boolean equals (Object other)...
```

i.e. the parameter must be an Object. Also you should implement hashCode too. See http://java67.blogspot.com.br/2013/04/example-of-overriding-equals-hashcode-compareTo-java-method.html for more information.